# Pagination while using a GET variable

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have had a difficult time paginating the code below.  I think it has to do with passing the GET variable $find on to the next page.

Anyway, how would I paginate the code below, so that the table below shows only 100 rows per page?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$find = strip_tags($_GET['find']);
$illegal = array("'", ".", "/", "\"", ";", "{", "}", "[", "]", "\\", "''", "'''", "''''", "'''''", "\\\\", "\\\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
$find = str_replace($illegal, '', $find);
$find = trim ($find);
$find = strtolower($find);
$find = stripslashes($find);
$_SESSION['find'] = $find;
?>

<?
if ($searching =="yes")
{

if ($find == "")
{
session_write_close();
header("Location:http://www.site.com/index.php");
exit;
unset($_SESSION['find']);   

}

mysql_connect("mysqlv10", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
$find = mysql_real_escape_string($find);

$result=mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM database LIKE '$find'")
or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
while($table=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
print "<p class=\"topic\">$table[0]</p>\n";
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * , votes_up - votes_down AS effective_vote FROM `$table[0]` WHERE site != '' ORDER BY effective_vote DESC");

print "<table class=\"navbar\">\n";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){

$effective_vote = $row['votes_up'] - $row['votes_down']; 

print "<tr>";

print "<td class='sitename'>".'<a type="amzn" category="products" class="links2">'.$row['site'].'</a>'."</td>";

print "<td class='votes'>".'<span class="votes_count" id="votes_count'.$row['id'].'">'.number_format($effective_vote).'</span>'."</td>";
print "<td class='ballot'>".'<span class="button" id="button'.$row['id'].'">'.'<a href="javascript:;" class="cell1" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.vote.'</a>'.'</span>'."</td>";
}
print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `LIMIT` in your query to tell the database how many rows you want and where to start from.

Pass along a parameter that tells the script that you want another chunk of the results and not just the first batch.

So for the link you can pass along the `page` parameter:

```
example.com/results.php?page=2
```

Where `page=` will tell the script what page you want to return.

Then you'll want to `LIMIT` the number of rows returned each time so that you have consistent paging.

```
$results_cnt = 100; //--rows you want per page of results
```

Now in your script you'll check to see if the `page` variable has been set. If not, default the start row to return from the first. But as you want to return different pages/sets of results, a little math is needed in order to start at the proper row.

```
if(isset($_GET["page"]) //--see if the variable is even there
{
    $page_num = (int)$_GET["page"]; //--forcing it to always be an integer

    $start_row = $results_cnt * ($page_num - 1);

    /* --
     what happens:
       ($results_cnt currently at 100)

     on page one (page=1), start at row 0
      math: 100 * (1 - 1) = 0

     on page two (page=2), start at row 100
      math: 100 * (2 - 1) = 100

     on page three (page=3), start at row 200
      math: 100 * (3 - 1) = 200

     etc.
    */
}
else
    $start_row = 0;
```

Now, having set the correct starting row, adjust the SQL query to use the variables like so:

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT *, votes_up - votes_down AS effective_vote 
                   FROM `$table[0]`
                   WHERE site != '' 
                   ORDER BY effective_vote DESC
                   LIMIT $start_row, $results_cnt");
```

Every time you hit the page it will be checking to see if `$_GET["page"]` is there. If not, then display from the first row. If it is, do the maths and work out how many rows to pass over and show the next page of.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
LIMIT (<pagenumber*amount of records you want to display>,< amount of records you want to display >)
```

in your SQL statement